# How to add video in pdf to create interactive pdf with android PdfDocument

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I was able to create pdf using below android API:

```
PdfDocument
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument

But how to add video into pdf. So far I don't find any example or document which say it support for adding video into pdf.

Comment: I think you cant add video inside pdf, but instead of that you can add your video thumbnail inside pdf.